# Как реализовать навигацию на сайте

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Imgur]

Есть макет, как видно по картинке, есть 4 страницы, 1 страница на весь дисплей,

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```

это первая страница, 2 страница, такие же свойства, только 
    left:100%;

3 страница, также, только топ 100%, и 4, топ 100% и лефт 100%. 
Эти блоки, лежат в общем блоке, для того что бы скрыть скролы по х и у.
свойства это блока

```
width: 100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
```

в этом фиксированном блоке, будет также блок навигации, фиксированный. Теперь, что я хочу. Каждый блок(страница) будет якорем для ссылок, т.е. у них будет соответствующий id, у блока(страницы 1) id="page1" и 2 страницы id="page2" и т.д. В навигации, ссылки типа

```
<a href="#page1"></a>
<a href="#page2"></a>
<a href="#page3"></a>
<a href="#page4"></a>
```

При клике на ссылку, чтобы отображалась страница (блок), с плавным перещением. Т.е. плавный скрол ходил по оси х и у. 
Я думаю вы меня поняли, и посоветуете, как решить такую задачу.
Большое спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Плавного перемещения можно добиться с помощью animate+scrollTop ([например](https://jsfiddle.net/Sysanin/7pn7c26c/49/))

```
$('#link_2').click(function(e) { 
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#page_2').offset().top }, 2500);
});
```

Но для ваших целей идеально подходит [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) (не путать со scrollTop :) )

Изучите демо на странице scrollTo - там даже есть то, что вам надо. Скачайте исходники и поковыряйтесь в них.